# CSS - one 100% width element or two 50% width elements on a line depending on screen size

Tags: css

I want to display a number (1..n) of pie charts. If the screen is large enough I'd like to display two to a line, but if not each one needs to be 100% width. Is this possible with just CSS? If not, what's the cleanest way to achieve it?

My current attempt is setting the `min-width` of the pie chart divs to the width available on the smallest screen size we are supporting (which leaves 500px available), so something like this:

```
div.piechart {
  min-width: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
}
```

This works for the smallest screen size and it works for screens with > 1000px available, but with > 500 and < 1000 it doesn't work.

Comment: Which browser version are you trying to support?

Comment: The current and most recent previous version of Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Comment: Better if you use the serve-side language to check the screen and loads a certain css file.

Comment: What if they resize the browser window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First solution supported by all browsers

This solution is supported in all browsers. Use floating (or inline-block) along with defined element dimensions. Whenever there's enough available content there will be more elements per row, but when content size is to narrow it will adopt accordingly.

```
.item
{
    display: inline-block;
    // or
    float: left;

    width: 300px;
}
```

### Second solution for latest browsers

This one uses different CSS settings for different browser window size. *to be continued*

[This blog post](http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/) outlines this functionality pretty neatly and basically does this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 800px)" href="800.css" />
```

### Third solution is using Javascript

You can always resort to Javascript in the end to support older browsers and also have your elements with exactly 50% or 100% width setting.

I would do it this way:

```
.item
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.small
{
    width: 50% !important;
}
```

`!important` rule is only needed if resizable elements' styles that define their widths are defined afterwards. If `.small` is the last one you can omit `!important` rule.

Then have items defined as:

```
<div class="item resizable">...</div>
```

And with the help of a library like jQuery or similar attach a window resize event handler to check browser window width and add/remove additional CSS classes to resizable elements:

```
var width = ...
if (width < 1000)
{
    $(".item.resizable").addClass("small");
}
else
{
    $(".item.resizable").removeClass("small");
}
```

Or write less lines of code if you know what you're doing:

```
var width = ...
var e = $(".item.resizable");
width < 1000 && e.addClass("small") || e.removeClass("small");
```

Comment: Your first solution is essentially a fixed width version of what I have now - but I really need the widths to be either 50% or 100%...

Comment: Thanks for the link about screen size dependant stylesheets - I didn't know about that. Unfortunately I have to support the most recent previous version of each of the major browsers and as far as I can see this won't work on IE8. Here's to the future though!

Comment: @Russell: I've also added third solution that uses a little bit of Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements can be displayed inline (`display:inline;`), you should just be able to leave them like that (with a fixed width), and the browser should fit them onto two lines when the size reduces.

To see what I mean, try opening this as HTML, and then resizing the browser a bit:

    `<html>
    <body>
    <span style="width:500px; background-color:blue;">1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</span>
    <span style="width:500px; background-color:red;">22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222</span>
    </body>
    </html>`

Other than that, you would probably need to use Javascript.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you'd rather created a JSFiddle and provided a link to it?

Comment: I don't want fixed width elements, I want them to be either 50% or 100% width.

Comment: So they're both 50%, until the screen size is > XX. Oh, well then you need JS. Look at Robert Koritnik's answer above. @Robert Yes, it probably would. I'll do that next time.

Answer (score 0):

Unless anyone can tell me a better way (please do!) of doing this I'm going to do it with jQuery:

In `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(this).width() >= 1300){
    $('div.piechart').addClass('fifty');    
  } else {
    $('div.piechart.fifty').removeClass('fifty');
  } 
}).resize();
```

And in the CSS:

```
div.piechart {
  width: 100%;
}

div.piechart.fifty {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use media queries to do this:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/
- http://mediaqueri.es/
- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Y97QL/show/ (change the width of the browser window)

```
.piechart {
    width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
    .piechart {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

Some older browsers (IE7/8) [do not support media queries](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries).

If you need to support those browsers, you should include a JavaScript polyfill, such as [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond).